# TypeScript: Problem typing a custom Form hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, use-reducer, react-custom-hooks

I know this is gonna be messy and terrible but while I have the TypeScript basics down, I'm having trouble typing the more advanced concepts, particularly typing useReducer hooks.
Here's my code with what I have so far, but I understand I have probably mistyped some items.

```
import { useCallback, useReducer } from 'react';

interface Inputs {
  id: string;
  value: string;
  inputIsValid: boolean;
}

interface FormState {
  inputs: Inputs[];
  isValid: boolean;
}

interface FormAction {
  inputs: Inputs;
  type: string;
  value: string;
  inputId: string;
  isValid: boolean;
  formIsValid: boolean;
}

const formReducer = (state: FormState, action: FormAction): FormState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INPUT_CHANGE':
      let formIsValid = true;
      for (const inputId in state.inputs) {
        if (!state.inputs[inputId]) continue;
        if (inputId === action.inputId)
          formIsValid = formIsValid && action.isValid;
        else formIsValid = formIsValid && state.inputs[inputId].inputIsValid;
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        inputs: {
          ...state.inputs,
          [action.inputId]: { value: action.value, isValid: action.isValid },
        },
        isValid: formIsValid,
      };
    case 'SET_DATA':
      return {
        inputs: action.inputs,
        isValid: action.formIsValid,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const useForm = (
  initialInputs: Inputs,
  initialFormValidity: boolean
) => {
  const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, {
    inputs: initialInputs,
    isValid: initialFormValidity,
  });
  const inputHandler = useCallback(
    (id: string, value: string, isValid: boolean) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'INPUT_CHANGE',
        value: value,
        isValid: isValid,
        inputId: id,
      });
    },
    []
  );
  const setFormData = useCallback(
    (inputData, formValidity: boolean) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_DATA',
        inputs: inputData,
        formIsValid: formValidity,
      });
    },
    []
  );
  return [formState, inputHandler, setFormData];
};
```

I also have a custom Input component that uses the formHook. This is all used from following Max Schwarzmuellers MERN stack course, which is super helpful but doesn't include typing. I've tried following his typescript course but haven't finished it yet.
My main problems come with the useReducer functions, which are overloaded with issues. Which look something like this:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: FormState, action: FormAction) => FormState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: FormState, action: FormAction) => FormState, initialState: FormState, initializer?: undefined): [FormState, Dispatch<...>]', gave the following error.
    Type 'Inputs' is not assignable to type 'Inputs[]'.ts(2769)
form-hook.tsx(10, 3): The expected type comes from property 'inputs' which is declared here on type 'FormState'
```

Edit:
Changed `Inputs` to `Inputs[]` and changed `FormState` to

```
type FormAction =
  | { type: 'INPUT_CHANGE'; value: string; inputId: string; isValid: boolean }
  | { type: 'SET_DATA'; formIsValid: boolean; inputs: Inputs[] };
```

Courtesy of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KzQ9xFSAEU which I highly recommend to anyone trying to understand using useReducer with TypeScript
Also thank you to everyone else who contributed, this was definitely a great learning experience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `initialInputs` is typed to `Inputs` when it should be `Inputs[]`. So you need to re-type that arg on `useForm`.

```
export const useForm = (
  initialInputs: Inputs[],
  initialFormValidity: boolean
) => {
  const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, {
    inputs: initialInputs,
    isValid: initialFormValidity
  });
```

Probably this needs changing in the action type as well? The change probably will lead you to more changes, but the above should fix the error you were seeing and uncover the rest.

Comment: That solved the useReducer problem so thank you! I still have issues with the dispatch types because it's missing the FormAction inputs...

Comment: Its related I think to that the action is just `Inputs` and not `Inputs[]`. Also `setFormData` is missing a type on `inputData`